# Show Hidden Div with effect When user clicks on a Button then toggle the process ( need jQuery solution )

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a google map section in my website. And i need it to be hidden by default. And when user click on the **LOCATE ON GOOGLE MAP** [ You can see the provided screenshot ] button then the google map section needs to show with effect. Then need to toggle the process.

Here is a screenshot:
[Collapsible Google Map Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6AzF.png)

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<section class="goolge-map-section">
        <!-- Toggle Button Area -->
        <div class="toggle-map-button">
            <button id="mapToggle" class="gmap-btn btn-block">Locate on google map<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>                
        </div>

        <!-- Google Map -->
        <div class="google-map" id="gmap-wrapper"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just hide the map after the DOM is rendered, and then display it when the user clicks on the toggle button? Something like the following would work I guess:

```
var $map = $('.google-map');
var $toggleButton = $('.toggle-map-button');

$map.hide();

$toggleButton.click(function() {
    $map.slideToggle();
});
```

Let me know if you run into any problems.

**Edit:** Try to wrap the map within a container div. Something like this:

```
<div class="google-map-container">
    <div class="google-map" id="gmap-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to rename the selector: `var $map = $('.google-map-container');`

Comment: Hello Json, Thanks for your solution. It just worked perfect, But after following your process a am facing a bit problem with the google map. **Map is not loading**. Your can take a look at here http://prntscr.com/9baozf

Comment: Hello Json, Thanks for your solution it just worked perfect :) . But having a bit issue with my google map section now :( . Seems the map isn't loading after following your process. Can you give a solution for this?? Here is a snap of the Issue http://prntscr.com/9baozf

Comment: Thank you JasonK. But it didn't worked! One important thing i am running the gmap script and toogle button script on Document Ready Function.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. With animation, use `slideToggle()` or `fadeToggle()`.
2. Without animation, define a class `.hidden {display: none}` and give `toggleClass("hidden")`.

Make sure you give this inside the `document`'s `ready` function.

**Solution**

```
$(function () {
    $(".mapToggle").click(function () {
        $('.toggle-map-button').slideToggle(); // Replace with either 1, or 2.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `fadeToggle()` of jquery.

```
$( "#mapToggle" ).click(function() {
  $( ".google-map" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" ); //Slow or dureation in miliseconds say 3000
});
```

See the working [fiddle as example](http://jsfiddle.net/6jLyzqhd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Hide the div initially using CSS :

```
#gmap-wrapper {
  display: none; 
}
```

Then use jQuery to toggle between display:none and display: block :

```
$( "#mapToggle" ).click(function(){
      $("#gmap-wrapper").toggle();
    });
```

**Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/asc9e728/

Answer (score 0):

Add display:none; to hide gmap-wrapper div.

```
<div class="google-map" id="gmap-wrapper" style="display:none;"></div>
```

or hide using jQuery:

```
$('#gmap-wrapper').hide();
```

This jQuery code can do the toggle with transition effect

```
$('#mapToggle').click(function(){
    $('#gmap-wrapper').toggle(500); // `slideToggle` or `fadeToggle` instead of `toggle`

});
```